# How to apply if else in sql query

Tags: mysql

i have written a sql query to fetch product now i want to apply a where clause in my query but for where i have there condition

```
if stock = 'in':
 where will be num>0:

if stock = 'out':
where will be num = 0;
 if stock = ' ':
no where clause will apply
```

i write this for two condtions

```
where       
   case 
      when stock='in' then num_in_stock > 0
      when stock ='out' then num_in_stock = 0
   end;
```

but it is not working. I am getting an error:

> (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ';    as a where a.partner_id = 5
>   order by a.date_updat' at line 20")
>   I am getting stock variable by

```
stock = request.GET.get('stock')
```

My full query is

```
 SELECT distinct a.product_id, a.variant_id 
    from 
    (
        SELECT cp.id as variant_id,
        COALESCE(cp.parent_id,cp.id) as product_id,
        ps.partner_id as partner_id,
        ps.price_retail as price_retail,
        COALESCE(oc.order_count,0) as order_count,
        cp.date_updated as date_updated
        FROM partner_stockrecord as ps 
        LEFT JOIN catalogue_product as cp on cp.id = ps.product_id 
        LEFT JOIN (
            select product_id,count(product_id) as order_count 
            from order_line group by product_id) as oc on oc.product_id = ps.id 
            where ((''' + stock +''') = 'in' and num_in_stock > 0 ) or
                ((''' + stock +''') = 'out' and num_in_stock = 0 );


        ) 
    as a where a.partner_id = '''+ str(partner_obj.id) +''' order by a.date_updated desc;
    ''');
```

Comment: can u write full query, and please remove semicolon (;) from end

Answer (score 5):

Convert:

```
 where 
    case 
       when stock='in' then num_in_stock > 0
       when stock ='out' then num_in_stock = 0
    end
```

into:

```
where (stock = 'in' and num_in_stock > 0 ) or
      (stock = 'out' and num_in_stock = 0 )
```

`CASE` is an *expression* that simply returns a scalar value. It cannot be used to control flow of execution in SQL.

Comment: it through an error (1054, "Unknown column 'stock' in 'where clause'").stock is my variable name which i am getting from frontend

Comment: @vikrantVerma That's a different issue. There is no such variable in the query you have posted. Instead you seem to be using a regular table field like `num_in_stock`.

Comment: i use 'stock' instead of stock code run without any error but data showing is {"data": []}

Comment: @vikrantVerma I really can't help you unless you post some info pertinent to the issue that you mention. I tried to answer the issue mentioned, which is related to the usage of `CASE`.

Comment: You have to use string concatenation in this case. Something like: `where (''' + stock +''') = 'in'`

Comment: `((''' + stock +''') = 'in' and num_in_stock > 0 )` but this error comes `(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'in) = 'in' and num_in_stock > 0 ) or\n                    ((in)= 'out' and num_in' at line 15")`

Comment: @vikrantVerma The second concatenation of `stock` is without single quotes as far as I can see. The resultant query should be ` ('in'= 'out' and num_in' at line 15")`

Comment: please take a look into my ques

Comment: @vikrantVerma This is a bug related to the way your code builds up the query string. Your initial post asked a completely different question. I tried to answer the initial question.